# PYQT5 QWebEngineView low quality when printing

Tags: printing, pyqt5, qwebengineview, qprinter

I am trying to print page from url using **QWebEngineView** in **PyQt5**. In preview **QWebEngineView.show()** it shows with normal quality, but when I print the page the quality is the lowest

First I thought that the problem is the bad printing device.
But when I print the content of `QTextEdit()` using  `QTextEdit().document().print_()` the quality was perfect

```py
import os
import sys
import argparse

from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import win32print

class PrinterView(QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, url=None, filename=None, do_preview=False, parent=None):
        super(PrinterView, self).__init__(parent)
        win32print.SetDefaultPrinter("XP-80C") 
        self.do_preview = do_preview
       
        self.load(QUrl('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710994/create-a-pdf-with-fillable-fields-python'))
        self.setZoomFactor(1)
      
      
        self.printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        self.printer.setOrientation(QPrinter.Portrait)
        self.printer.setFullPage(True)

        self.loadFinished.connect(self.onloadFinished)

    def print_completed(self, dsd):
        pass

    def onloadFinished(self):
        if self.do_preview:
            self.show()
        else:
            self.page().print(self.printer, self.print_completed)
```

**Here is the printed version of stackoverflow page**

[image: Printed version]

Comment: It might be a problem related to the font color, and the printer driver may try to use that mode when the color is not plain black. Ensure that you're using [`setColorMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#setColorMode) to `GrayScale`, and also do some tests with local files using different colors to see the result. You may need to override the font color with a custom stylesheet to ensure that it's completely black, not a lighter shade.

Comment: @musicamante, Thank you for your response. I tried to set color mode, but nothing changes

Comment: Then I suggest to do some tests with local files and see the result as suggested above. Also, check other options in the printer, possibly using [QPrinterDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprintdialog.html), you might find some options that can be set for the QPrinter object.

Comment: @musicamante I did some tests with local files, I printed an .pdf file and there is low quality only on images and snapshots . It seems when printing from QWebEnginePage it prints page as image

Comment: Did you test with *local files* on QWebEnginePage? That's the issue, if you try to use QPrinter on a different object (like QTextDocument) it won't matter, the source of the problem is clearly the web engine

Comment: @musicamante, Yes, of course first I tried with local files with `QWebEngineView.setHtml()`, I did not bring it here in stackoverflow because it would be a long code. After printing QWebEngineView into PDF I understand that the content was the image.